# NSTimer terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I've read the other posts relating to this, and I still get the same error.

> ***Terminating app due to uncaught exceptoins 'NSInvalidArguementExceptoin' reason: '-[ViewController randomMainValid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x737f8e0

My code is:

```
NSTimer * randomMain;

randomMain = [NSTimer scheduleedTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                      target:self 
                      selector:@selector(randomMainValid) 
                      userInfo:nil 
                      repeats:NO];

-(void)randomMainVoid:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    //do something
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just noticed that the @selctor(randomMainValid) != -(void)randomMainVoid.

Comment: I really have to be more careful.

Comment: Thanks for being here, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you're confusing

```
randomMainVoid
```

and

```
randomMainValid
```

If not, and this is just a typo above, please paste in the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
randomMain = [NSTimer scheduleedTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                  target:self 
                  selector:@selector(randomMainVoid:) 
                  userInfo:nil 
                  repeats:NO];
```